# Get Angular router link item to be selected by default

Tags: angular, angular-router

When `employees.component.html` loads, none of the `nav` link items are selected. How would I get the `About` link item to be selected by default when `employees.component.html` loads?

```
// employees.component.html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="nav nav-pills">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="about" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="schedule" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Schedule</a>
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="contact" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>

// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: Constant.WEB_URL_PREFIX + '/employees', component: EmployeesComponent},
  {
    path: Constant.WEB_URL_PREFIX + '/employees/:employeeId', component: EmployeeComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
      {path: 'schedule', component: ScheduleComponent},
      {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

I have read a solution where you can update app-routing.module.ts empty path to point to `AboutComponent` to have `{path: '', component: AboutComponent}`. I am not convinced that this is the preferred solution, and seems more of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

The routerLinkActive uses the current url in order to put the given class name on the anchor element. This means that you need to be on this path in order for the class to be set on the element. In your case why don't you just use the [ngClass] directive or the class binding and do something like `<a class="nav-link" routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active" [class.active]="isDefault">About</a>` and inside your component you can set the `isDefault` class property to true or false depending on the location that you are currently at. You could use the ActivatedRoute service or the Router service in order to get the current url.

If you go with this approach probably a good idea would be to dynamically set the routerLink value because otherwise event though about is active someone might click on it which would result in something that you probably don't want so just in case you can `<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="aboutLinkPath" routerLinkActive="active" [class.active]="isDefault">About</a>` and set the aboutLinkPath to `'.'` when isDefault is true and `'about'` when isDefault is false.